# Can I select the lattest insert rows in mysql when rows have the same date?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
+------+-----------------------------+---------+
| date |           test              | number  |
+------+-----------------------------+---------+
| 12.1 | hello!                      | 10      |
| 12.1 | hello and welcome!          | 15      |
| 12.2 | come here!                  | 20      |
| 12.2 | come here and do something! | 10      |
+------+-----------------------------+---------+
```

the rows with date `12.1` and date `12.2` are inserted at different times, can I select the lattest insert one?
as result:

```
+------+-----------------------------+---------+
| date |           test              | number  |
+------+-----------------------------+---------+
| 12.1 | hello and welcome!          | 15      |
| 12.2 | come here and do something! | 10      |
+------+-----------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: do you have an auto_increment `id`? you can select the latest record using `MAX(id)`

Comment: Why don't you put a timestamp in your row that records the insert time of each record?  Alternatively, add a unique id for each row. A good database design will save you much effort in the future.

Comment: if the rows with date 12.1 are not inserted anymore while other rows with date 12.2 or 12.3 or any other are inserted constantly, then how can I select the rows with date 12.1.

Comment: I think I understand what is he trying to do here. I assume that he is fetching the latest inserted `test` field for each date.

Comment: Yes,I agreed with this @MarcAudet

Answer (score 0):

Your table have an auto_increment id?

if you want the last of all the rows in the table

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to select the latest test for each date. Try this:

```
SELECT tb2.date, tb1.test, tb1.number 
       FROM (SELECT MAX(number) as number, date FROM tb1 GROUP BY date) AS tb2, tb1
       WHERE tb1.date = tb2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this sql can help u

```
SELECT tb.date, tb.test, tb.number
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT date, test, number
    FROM test
    ORDER BY date DESC
) AS tb
GROUP BY tb.date
```

table like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
`date` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`test` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`number` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `test` (`date`, `test`, `number`) VALUES
('12.1', 'hello!', 10),
('12.1', ' hello and welcome!', 15),
('12.2', 'come here!', 20),
('12.2', 'come here and do something!', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want create a new field `created_at with datatype (timestamp) and ORDER BY created_at DESC`  or you can if you had `field id` you use `ORDER BY id DESC`.

Comment: if I created a new column of tiemstamp the how to select the rows with the max timestamp